# Break not working inside my if statement

Tags: python

Looking for some help with the following block of code.

```
## This is a number guessing game!

import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName= input()

number= random.randint(1, 20)
print ('Well, '+ myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print ('Take a guess.')
    guess=input()
    guess=int(guess)

    if guess < number:
        print ('Your guess is too low.')

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is to high!')

    if guess == number:
        break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken+1)
        print('Good job,  '+ myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
    if guess != number:
            number= str(number)
            print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number + '.')
```

Comment: Not working how? What happens?

Comment: Must-haves of all error descriptions: ① What is being done, ② What outcome is expected, ③ What outcome is observed instead.  I guess your `break` is working just fine and bails out of your `for`-loop at once.  So you never reach the next `if guess == number:` line below the `break`.

Comment: your break works fine, first un-indent the last two `if`, to see it work set `number` to 10 and guess 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the code beyond `break` to execute, I would change your code to

```
    ## This is a number guessing game!

import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName= input()

number= random.randint(1, 20)
print ('Well, '+ myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print ('Take a guess.')
    guess=input()
    guess=int(guess)

    if guess < number:
        print ('Your guess is too low.')

    elif guess > number:
        print('Your guess is to high!')

    elif guess == number:
        # print 'Good job' here instead of beyond the break in a separate if statement
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken+1)
        print('Good job,  '+ myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
        break

    if guessesTaken == 5:
        number= str(number)
        print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number + '.')
```

This way the program checks if your guesses are up - `if guessesTaken == 5:` and if you guess the number then it breaks after printing `good job` etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this: (give it a try)

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName= input()

number= random.randint(1, 20)
print ('Well, '+ myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
print(number)

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print ('Take a guess.')
    guess=input()
    guess=int(guess)

    if guess < number:
        print ('Your guess is too low.')

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is to high!')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken+1)
    print('Good job,  '+ myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
if guess != number:
    number= str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number + '.')
```

You shouldn't indent this:

```
if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken+1)
    print('Good job,  '+ myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
if guess != number:
    number= str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number + '.')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

maxGuesses =  6
guessed    = False
myName     = input('Hello! What is your name? ')
number     = random.randint(1, 20)
print ('Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.'.format(myName))

for guessesTaken in range(1, maxGuesses + 1):
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))

    if guess < number:
        print ('Your guess is too low!')

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is to high!')

    if guess == number:
        guessed = True
        break

if guessed:
    print('Good job, {0}! You guessed my number in {1} guesses!'.format(myName, guessesTaken))
    print("Congrats you win!")
elif not guessed:
    print("Shucks, you lose!")
```

Your break works but the error you are getting is that when you use break the loop ends and doesn't reach the next condition.

*** Above code is a little neater ***